# PPF 3D Models Matching OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, computer-vision, mesh

I am developing an application that:

1. Reads 7 model files and trains a PPF 3D Detector;
2. Reads a scene file and try to match with the detector;
3. Store the result on a file (visual retrieving).

I was following the [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/surface_matching/doc/surface_matching.html) , but there are a few things that I didn't understand even reading the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d25/classcv_1_1ppf__match__3d_1_1PPF3DDetector.html#gsc.tab=0):

1. The **detector.match()** stores on  **results**  the *poses* of the model on the scene. But as far as I understand, a *pose* is the position and the orientation of the model, but how will I know which model is?
2. When I print the pose of the first result, it gives me a 4x4 table with float values on it. Where can I find what do they mean?
3. Still on pose printing, it gives me the *Model Index* which, at first, I thought that was the number of the model I used to train the detector. The problem is: I used 7 models to train the detector and the first result gives me  **"Pose to Model Index 12"**. So I thought it was the Model Description Index as it is on  Drost(2012). But if it really is the Model Description Index, how can I know to which Model this index belongs?
4. According to the tutorial, using **transformPCPose** and writing it to a PLY file would give a visual result of the matching, but the  [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html#ga59e4bcba08456d1ff8728a6ea8bc16d2&gsc.tab=0) says that it returns a 4x4 pose matrix, but I am still printing it and it gives me a weird image with more than 16 vertices, so I didn't understand what the tutorial was doing. How can I write the visual result on a file like the tutorial did?

I also read that ICP is used to correct any pose error, but using PPF without ICP gives acceptable results. Anyway I tried to use ICP but it always gave me the "Bad argument error".

The code I used is written bellow:

```
void computer_vision_3d(string in_path)
{
    Mat files_clouds[NUM_OF_FILES];                                 // > Stores the point cloud of all objects
    Mat scene_cloud;                                                // > Stores the scene point cloud
    ppf_match_3d::PPF3DDetector 
        detector(RELATIVE_SAMPLING_STEP, RELATIVE_DISTANCE_STEP);   // > Matches the model with the scene
    vector<Pose3DPtr> results;                                      // > Stores the results of the processing

        // ! Phase 1 - Train Model
    scene_cloud = loadPLYSimple(DEFAULT_SCENE_PATH.c_str(), PARAM_NORMALS);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FILES; i++)
    {   
            // . Init Point Cloud
        string file_path = DEFAULT_OBJECT_PATH + to_string(i) + ".ply";
        files_clouds[i] = loadPLYSimple(file_path.c_str(), PARAM_NORMALS);

            // . Train Model
        detector.trainModel(files_clouds[i]);
    }

        // ! Phase 2 - Detect from scene
    detector.match( scene_cloud, results, 
                RELATIVE_SCENE_SAMPLE_STEP, RELATIVE_SCENE_DISTANCE);
    
        // ! Phase 3 - Results
    if(results.size() > 0)
    {
        Pose3DPtr result = results[0];
        result->printPose();

            // ! Transforms the point cloud to the model pose
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FILES; i++)
        {
            Mat pct = transformPCPose(files_clouds[i], result->pose);
            string f_name = "match" + to_string(i) + ".ply";
            writePLY(pct, f_name.c_str());
        }
    }

}
```

One of the models, the scene and the result:

[image: Figure 1 One of the seven models]
Figure 1 - One of the seven models. 
[image: Figure 2 The scene]
Figure 2 - The scene.
[image: Figure 3 The weird result] 
Figure 3 - The weird result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the author of that module, I would like to address your questions:

*1. The detector.match() stores on results the poses of the model on the scene.   But as far as I understand, a pose is the position and the orientation of the model, but how will I know which model is?*

There is only a single model. So poses are for different hypotheses of the same model

*2. When I print the pose of the first result, it gives me a 4x4 table with float values on it. Where can I find what do they mean?*

It is an augmented matrix of [R|t] with the extra row of [0,0,0,1] to homogenize.

*3. Still on pose printing, it gives me the Model Index which, at first, I thought that was the number of the model I used to train the detector. The problem is: I used 7 models to train the detector and the first result gives me "Pose to Model Index 12". So I thought it was the Model Description Index as it is on Drost(2012). But if it really is the Model Description Index, how can I know to which Model this index belongs?*

It is the ID of the matching model point (correspondence) not the model id. As I said, multiple models are not supported.

*3. According to the tutorial, using transformPCPose and writing it to a PLY file would give a visual result of the matching, but the documentation says that it returns a 4x4 pose matrix, but I am still printing it and it gives me a weird image with more than 16 vertices, so I didn't understand what the tutorial was doing. How can I write the visual result on a file like the tutorial did?*

The function transforms a point cloud with a given pose. It will only give correct results if your pose is correct. I don't think that the pose outcome of your implementation is correct. The "Bad argument" exception in the ICP is also probably because of that.

And one more note: Always make sure that the model and scene have the surface normals, which are correctly oriented towards the camera.

Comment: Thanks! When I asked this question I didn't understand very much from computer vision, now I understand a bit more and I see that I done a lot of things wrong...

Comment: Can you expand on the bit "correctly oriented towards the camera"? I see that you set the viewpoint before computing normals (in the example code which calculates the normals), but how are surface normals related to the camera viewpoint?

Comment: Good question. Check the end of the 'Theoretical Primer' section of :
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php

Comment: Ok, understood, the question is whether normals are indeed oriented from the object to the outside, right? I have the CAD model which I sample using CloudCompare (and some further rather manual magic to get usable model, like removal of hidden stuff), and I obtain the normals directly from the STL mesh. In this case, no viewpoint is needed.